# How to write a SPARQL CONSTRUCT query that returns an RDF list?

Tags: sparql, rdf, graph-databases

Suppose I have the following RDF triples expressed in Turtle:

```
@prefix sorg: <http://www.schema.org/> .

<https://example.com/Foo> sorg:hasPart ( "item1" "item2" "item3" ) .
```

How do I write a SPARQL `CONSTRUCT` query that retrieves the list back out? If it's not possible, how can I write a `SELECT` query that will return the list elements in the correct order? I found [this resource](http://www.snee.com/bobdc.blog/2014/04/rdf-lists-and-sparql.html), but it does not seem to guarantee that elements will be returned in order.

Comment: The question is, what would be the WHERE part? The subject? Or subject predicate? or only the predicate?

Answer (score 1):

This will do the construct for you - linked onto original property to obtain the list so you can filter etc. as required (Just change ?thing and the property to your use case).

```
prefix rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

CONSTRUCT {
    ?thing <urn:prop:to:list> ?list .
    ?listRest rdf:first ?head ; 
       rdf:rest ?tail .
} WHERE {
    ?thing <urn:prop:to:list> ?list .

    ?list rdf:rest* ?listRest .
    ?listRest rdf:first ?head ;
       rdf:rest ?tail .
}
```

Comment: CONSTRUCT is inconsistent as it is missing a link between ?list and ?listRest

Answer (score 0):

You should try this query to solve the problem:

```
prefix rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

CONSTRUCT {
    ?thing <urn:prop:to:list> ?list .
    ?listItems ?p ?o .
} WHERE {
    ?thing <urn:prop:to:list> ?list .
    ?list rdf:rest*/rdf:first? ?listItems .
    ?listItems ?p ?o .
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).